# How to add delay to Tri-state Buffer

Tags: verilog, delay, assign, bidirectional, inout

I'm new to verilog, thus I have very simple question. I want to add delay before `data_in` assign to `pad` in following statement

> assign pad = (enable) ? data_in : 1'bz;

something like

```
assign pad = (enable) ? #10 data_in : 1'bz;
```

but it won't work. What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the delay before between `assign` and `pad`

```
assign #10 pad = (enable) ? data_in : 1'bz;
```

This delay will effect will be seen on the data_in and the switching to high-Z.
You can control the rise, fail, and turn-off time separately. For example:

```
assign #(10,10,0) pad = (enable) ? data_in : 1'bz;
```

There is no turn-on time, so if you only want the delay on `data_in`, you will need to create an intermittent assignment

```
wire #10 data_in_delayed = data_in;
assign pad = (enable) ? data_in_delayed : 1'bz;
```

You can learn more about assign statements with delay in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 10.3 *Continuous assignments*. Note SystemVerilog allows assign statements on net and variable types, Verilog only support net types.

Also, be aware that `#` delays are ignored by synthesis. `#` delay is only for simulation.